# Flutter multiple WebView widget error "Bad state: Future already completed"

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, future, flutter-cupertino

My goal is to make a `WebView` app with several `CupertinoTabViews` that when clicking each `BottomNavigationBarItem`, `CupertinoTabScaffold` shows different `WebView` containing widgets; `pageA` and `pageB`.

As the application launches, the first WebView successfully shows the initial URL webpage.
However, when clicking another Tab button (trying to show another WebView), *Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Future already completed* is thrown.

**main.dart**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _currentTabIndex = 0;

  PageWeb pageA;
  PageWeb pageB;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pageA = new PageWeb(this, ObjectKey(0), "A");
    pageB = new PageWeb(this, ObjectKey(1), "B");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Widget scaffold = CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        currentIndex: _currentTabIndex,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('A')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.photo), title: Text('B')),
        
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        CupertinoTabView returnValue;
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            returnValue = CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (context) {
                return pageA;
              },
            );
            break;
          case 1:
            returnValue = CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (context) {
                return pageB;
              },
            );
            break;
        }
        return returnValue;
      },
    );

    return scaffold;
  }
}
```

**pageweb.dart (PageWeb class)**

```
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

class PageWeb extends StatefulWidget {
  final delegate;
  final ObjectKey key;
  final String navTitle;

  PageWeb(this.delegate, this.key, this.navTitle);

  @override
  _PageWebState createState() {
    return _PageWebState();
  }
}

class _PageWebState extends State<PageWeb> {
  bool _isLoading = true;
  final cookieManager = WebviewCookieManager();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          middle: Text(widget.navTitle),
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
                child: new WebView(
          key: widget.key,
          initialUrl: "https://www.google.com/search?q=${widget.navTitle}",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
            // Here is the error occurring part.
          },
          onPageStarted: (String pageUrl) {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = true;
            });
          },
          onPageFinished: (String pageUrl) {
            setState(() {
              _isLoading = false;
            });
          },
        ))));
  }
}
```

*The Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Future already completed* error locates the following line:

```
_controller.complete(webViewController);
```

Comment: Why is your controller declared outside of a class?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I literally 'just' moved the variable inside the class and saw the comment. It works. Thank you. I am wondering why declaring the variable outside the class causes an error. Is it because the declared variable is being considered as a global variable?

Comment: Yes that's what it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simple. Move the `_controller` declaration inside the class.

Comment: it's working but what's the problem here to declare this controller outside of class ?